# Objective-C to Swift conversion for C function

Tags: objective-c, swift

I am facing difficulties in Objective-C to Swift conversion. How to write below code in Swift?

```
int mib[2];
size_t length;
mib[0] = CTL_HW;

mib[1] = HW_MEMSIZE;
length = sizeof(int64_t);
sysctl(mib, 2, &physicalMemorySize, &length, NULL, 0);

mib[1] = HW_USERMEM;
length = sizeof(int64_t);
sysctl(mib, 2, &userMemorySize, &length, NULL, 0);
```

Comment: Where's the Objective-C code?

Comment: This is objective C only.

Comment: No, that is C code. There is no Objective-C code in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not too difficult if one knows two things:

- The C `int` type is a 32-bit integer, this is `Int32` in Swift,
  not `Int`.
- `sizeof()` from C is `MemoryLayout<T>.stride` in Swift.

Then we get:

```
var mib : [Int32] = [ CTL_HW, HW_MEMSIZE ]
var physicalMemorySize: Int64 = 0
var size = MemoryLayout<Int64>.stride
if sysctl(&mib, UInt32(mib.count), &physicalMemorySize, &size, nil, 0) == 0 {
    print(physicalMemorySize)
} else {
    print("sysctl failed")
}
```

Comment: thanks! I was trying but was getting some error at sysctl function.

Comment: @user1101733: Why don't you add your attempt to the *question?* Then everybody sees that you tried something, and we can point out the exact problem.

Comment: yes,I will next time.     One question Why did you use 'stride' instead of size?

Comment: @user1101733: Swift distinguishes between "size" (size without struct padding) and "stride" (size including struct padding). They are equal for "simple types" like integer, and also equal for all types imported from C, so it would not make a difference here. But generally, "stride" is in Swift what "sizeof" is in C.

Comment: I was passing mib without & and was getting " Cannot convert value of type '[Int32]' to expected argument type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<Int32>!'". Could you please help me from where I can clear all these concepts? This is also working if we pass mib like this -UnsafeMutablePointer(mutating: mib).

Comment: Will study about it more the actual usage and difference between size and stride

Comment: @user1101733: This might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47610995/1187415.

Comment: Thanks @Martin R

Comment: @user1101733: The first parameter of sysctl is a *mutable* pointer, that's why you have to pass the array as "inout expression" with `&`. You'll find the details in https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html

Comment: ok. I need one more help from you please refer my other question.