# MemoryLayout in Swift

Tags: swift, struct, swift4, memory-layout

How does MemoryLayout calculate size for a struct ?

I read [this](https://swiftunboxed.com/internals/size-stride-alignment/) article, and I seemed to understand it pretty well, until I got stuck on the following problem:

```
struct CertifiedPuppy1 {
  let age: Int
  let isTrained: Bool
  let isCertified: Bool
}

MemoryLayout<CertifiedPuppy1>.size        // 10
MemoryLayout<CertifiedPuppy1>.stride      // 16
MemoryLayout<CertifiedPuppy1>.alignment   // 8

struct CertifiedPuppy2 {
  let isTrained: Bool
  let age: Int
  let isCertified: Bool
}

MemoryLayout<CertifiedPuppy2>.size        // 17
MemoryLayout<CertifiedPuppy2>.stride      // 24
MemoryLayout<CertifiedPuppy2>.alignment   // 8


struct CertifiedPuppy3 {
  let isTrained: Bool
  let isCertified: Bool
  let age: Int
}

MemoryLayout<CertifiedPuppy3>.size        // 16 <--why not 10, like for CertifiedPuppy1 ??--
MemoryLayout<CertifiedPuppy3>.stride      // 16
MemoryLayout<CertifiedPuppy3>.alignment   // 8
```

Question is, why does `CertifiedPuppy3` have size 16, instead of 10, like for `CertifiedPuppy1` ?

Comment: Each `Int` is aligned to a 8-byte boundary *and* has size 8.

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47610995/alignment-vs-stride-in-swift.

Comment: Ahh, you mean
CertifiedPuppy1: 8 + 1 + 1 + (buffer 6, ignored) = 10;
CertifiedPuppy3: 1 + 1 + (buffer 6, counted) + 8 = 16

Answer (score 4):

As I understand it, pretty much there is one main rule:

- start address of every object must be at a multiple of its *alignment*. That rule is applied for everything - properties in a struct (Int, Bool, etc.), struct itself, and all other types.

Image below shows the layouts of bytes for your examples.

Lets see your last example - CertifiedPuppy3:
- *alignment* for *isTrained* (Bool) is 1, that means it can start at any address, so it starts at 0.
- *alignment* for *isCertified* (Bool) is also 1, so there is no problem for isCertified to start at 1.
- *alignment* for *age* (Int) is 8, so it can start only on 0, 8, 16, 24... That is why start address of age is at 8, and not at 2. If it was at 2 it would be misaligned.

So CertifiedPuppy3 has size of 16 because its properties must follow alignment rules.

Non-related to question, there is also this:

- *alignment* of a struct is equal to maximum *alignment* of its properties.

That is why stride for CertifiedPuppy2 is 24: alignment for CertifiedPuppy2 is 8, since its size is is 17 next available position for start of new CertifiedPuppy2 object is at 24 - that is what stride is - minimum distance between two CertifiedPuppy2 objects.

*[image: alignment]*