# Does the order of declaring properties matter?

Tags: swift, memory-layout

According to working with [MemoryLayout](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/memorylayout), the following `Foo` and `Bar` structures would have the same values for `stride` and `alignment`:

```
struct Foo {
    let myInt: Int
    let myBool: Bool
}

struct Bar {
    let myBool: Bool
    let myInt: Int
}

print(MemoryLayout<Foo>.stride) // 16
print(MemoryLayout<Bar>.stride) // 16

print(MemoryLayout<Foo>.alignment) // 8
print(MemoryLayout<Bar>.alignment) // 8
```

which is seems to be expected. However when it comes to the `size`, it would be different:

```
print(MemoryLayout<Foo>.size) // 9
print(MemoryLayout<Bar>.size) // 16
```

In fact, I do know what is the reason of it; However, as a developer should I care about such a thing? will it be automatically optimized by the compiler?

<sub>**P.S:** My apologies if such a question should be asked at [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/), I am unsure about it</sub>

Comment: Compare  (possible duplicate?) [alignment vs stride in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47610995/alignment-vs-stride-in-swift) – the `size` does not include the trailing padding, that's why the order matters.

Comment: Thanks @MartinR. Does it mean that cost of `Bar` for the memory is more than `Foo` (even if it's couple of bits)? Naturally, we -as developers- should not care about it, but I was wondering if it makes any different no matter how it could be trivial.